# Bipartite Graphs and perfect matchings

Tags: graph-theory

I'm trying to prove that if $G$ is bi-partite and $d$-regular for $d \geq 1,$ then $G$ has a one-to-one and onto matching between the two partitions of the graph. I have a feeling that I need to use Hall's Condition to help prove this particular result, but I'm not entirely sure where. Here is my sketch so far: \
Because $G$ is bipartite, we can separate this graph into section $H$ and $I$ such that $\forall h \in H. \exists i \in I . h \sim i.$, $\forall h_1, h_2 \in H. h_1 \nsim h_2$, and $\forall i_1, i_2 \in I . i_1 \nsim i_2.$ (essentially, formal bipartite-ness). If we take $S \subset H$ arbitrary, we view $N(S)$ to be the neighborhood of $S.$ \
I would really like to show $|N(S)| \geq |S|,$ but I am having issues trying to show that formally. any suggestions?

Comment: Proceed by contradiction. Take an $S$ with $|N(S)|<|S|$. How many edges go between S and N(S)? Hint: Use the d-regularity.